# Problem with the \@whilenum

Tags: loops

I met the error `` You can't use `\spacefactor' in vertical mode. `` when using `\@whilenum` for a loop. Below is a minimum not-working example. Why is this wrong?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\title{loop}\author{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\@whilenum\value{section}<6\do{\section{more}}
\end{document}
```

### Error Message

> ```
> You can't use `\spacefactor' in vertical mode.
> \@->\spacefactor 
>                  \@m {}
> l.6 \@
>       whilenum\value{section}<6\do{\section{more}}
> Sorry, but I'm not programmed to handle this case;
> I'll just pretend that you didn't ask for it.
> If you're in the wrong mode, you might be able to
> return to the right one by typing `I}' or `I$' or `I\par'.
>
> ! Missing $ inserted.
> <inserted text> 
>                 $
> l.6 \@
>       whilenum\value{section}<6\do{\section{more}}
> I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
> you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.
> ```

Comment: the `@` is not a valid character in a macro name (at least not in a `.tex` file), so you need to make it valid with `\makeatletter` before you intend to use it.

Comment: @Lupino I converted your commend into a community answer. If you are not happy with that then let me know and I delete it.

Comment: *comment (typo in my previous comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following user Lupino's comment, I provide the following community answer. Please refer to [What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351) for information regarding `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\title{loop}\author{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\makeatletter % <-- Added
\@whilenum\value{section}<6\do{\section{more}}
\makeatother % <-- Added
\end{document}
```

[image]